# What does a hash do to a variable in VB?

Tags: text, printing, vb6, filestream

I have to refactor a VB6 program to C# and am stuck at understanding the following lines:

```
Set myFileSystemObject = New FileSystemObject
Set myTextStream = myFileSystemObject.OpenTextFile("myTextFile.txt")
Open sPrinterPort For Output As iFileNumber
Print #iFileNumber, myTextStream.ReadAll
Close #iFileNumber
```

I do know what's generally happening, but as I'm not used to the VB syntax, I'd like to know exactly what

```
Print #iFileNumber, myTextStream.ReadAll
```

does. And more specifically, what the `#` in front of `iFileNumber` does. Why is it there? Wouldn't the variable itself suffice to print on the stream?

This is merely for understanding exactly what's happening in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Print #iFileNumber, myTextStream.ReadAll` prints the string returned by `ReadAll` into the file opened by number `iFileNumber` (and because there is no semicolon after the statement, it also adds `vbNewLine` in the end.)

The `#` (for "number") is there since the old times. VB6 just supports it. It does nothing execution wise. It used to assist readability and make the language more natural-like. Speak out loud:

```
Open "1.txt" For Input As 1
```

vs.

```
Open "1.txt" For Input As #1
```

Comment: Actually `Print` and `Print #` are two different statements.  While there are places where the pound/number sign (gag, *please* not "hash") is optional this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Print #iFileNumber, myTextStream.ReadAll
```

While trying to understand this myself, I came across this [site](http://www.truebasic.com/node/1032) that has a section on printing to a printer. They say #some_integer indicates a channel number:

> A channel number is any integer value between 0 and 999, preceded by a pound sign (#); it indi- cates a specific channel to a device.
>
> A channel is a connection between your program and an input or output device, such as a printer or a file.