# vba: what does the pound sign (#) mean before variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing code to read lines from a text file and I came across this method:

```
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open "Filename" For Input As #FileNum
```

I understand that when `#` is placed after a variable it denotes it as a double but what does it mean when it is placed before the variable, as in `Open "Filename" For Input As #FileNum`?

Comment: This syntax is only used in file IO. The pound is defining which filestream you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The # (for "number") is there since the old times. VB6 just supports it. It does nothing execution wise. It used to assist readability and make the language more natural-like. Speak out loud:

```
Open "1.txt" For Input As 1
```

vs.

```
Open "1.txt" For Input As #1
```

Reference:-
[What does a hash do to a variable in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701599/what-does-a-hash-do-to-a-variable-in-vb?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This is just a verbatim copy-paste of the other answer. Link to it in a comment perhaps, but as it is this is borderline plagiarism. At the very least, make it clear that you are quoting someone else's answer.